# Push changes to master and update next release branch

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and have just been given responsibility for handling builds and releases.

We have a remote branch named 2.15. About 2 weeks ago someone else created a remote branch named 2.16; however, we've made changes to 2.15 since that time.

Today is release day, so I need to send all of the changes from 2.15 up until this point to the "master" and then pull them to 2.16 as well.

I've been digging around for the proper way to do this, but I'm not confident of the answer. I thought maybe I could do something like this:

```
git checkout 2.15
git pull origin 2.15
git push origin master
git checkout 2.16
git pull origin master
```

Am I close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to merge `2.15` into `master` and `2.16` and then push these two branches. Your commands are wrong, you need something like

```
git checkout master
git merge 2.15
git checkout 2.16
git merge 2.15
git push origin master 2.15 2.16
```

Of course you need to check that merges were correct and probably test the results before pushing.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have worked, and it made sense once I saw the answer; however, I do have one follow-up questions. What is the significance of the last line? Would that be the same as pushing to master, 2.15 and 2,16 individually, or does that establish a sort-of "upstream" order for git to follow--or something else entirely? Would like to ensure I fully understand.

Comment: @LawrenceH. no, that's the same as pushing them individually

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first ensure your local 2.15 and master branches contain all changes from the remote repo:-

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout 2.15
git pull origin 2.15
```

I assume you don't yet have a local 2.16 branch, so let's create it matching the remote brancb:-

```
git checkout -b 2.16 remote/2.16
```

Then, *assuming you want 2.16 changes in master*, merge changes from 2.15 in to 2.16 using:-

```
git merge 2.15
```

Then merge 2.16 (which now also contains 2.15) in to master:-

```
git checkout master
git merge 2.16
```

Finally push all those changes to your remote repo:-

```
git push origin master
git push origin 2.16
git push origin 2.15
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about making sure things were up to date. I found a "hotfix" that my boss threw in five hours after 2.15 should have been complete. It wasn't a problem, but the process went smoother because of that reminder. Everything else seems spot on as well, though I followed @wRAR steps for actual resolution.